# Best layout strategy if removing/adding components in a Java Swing UI?

Tags: java, swing

I have a dynamic java Swing form UI that needs to resize when a toggle button is pressed. Components inside the form panel need to be removed or added and the height accordingly reduced/increased.

Cardlayout allows me to switch between two panels with different components but the height is hardwired to the the tallest card. I need to dynamically remove swing components and reduce the height of the inner panels as well as the entire main panel.

Using Grouplayout with setHonorsVisibility(true) doesn't work either unless the entire layout hierarchy is re-created. There is no way to get rid of the gaps between components being hidden.

BoxLayout may sort of works but with a box container it will be a pain to layout the form elements to align nicely. So I haven't tried it.

I would like to work with Netbeans GUI builder if possible but the default GroupLayout doesn't work for me.  So looking at other design patterns/strategies to solve this.

I would hate to manually setPreffered dimensions on nested panels.

How to people deal with re-packing the UI after removing components ?

Comment: I have tried the setVisible() - pack - repaint - paradigm but can't get the gaps introduced by Netbeans GroupLayout to go away on turning components invisible.

Comment: I have looked at the GridBagLayout as an alternative, but my layout isn't overtly complex. All my components are arranged a row. So I just need to get rid of a row when hiding components. Would you still recommend the GridBagLayout ?

Comment: if each row is seperate, you could have a gridbag with multiple rows, and then each row be a nested panel that is some other layout.  you (presuming the gridbag is correctly configured) should just have to make the nested panel not visible to make the whole row disappear.  (after changing visibility, invalidate/revalidate/repaint) and the gridbag panel should resize appropriately.

Comment: John - You are suggesting a nested panel that spans all the columns of a row (GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL) ? Only issue is I won't be able to use the grid to layout the row components (label, combo-box, btn) to align with other rows or perhaps instead of using a nested panel, I could just make all the cells in a row  invisible/repaint - will that approach work ?   Also in a GridBagLayout is it possible to specify a constraint to keep button sizes fixed on resize ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going to have to go with a multi-pronged attack, like you've already laid out.

1) cardlayout for swapping - helps to keep unrelated things seperate

2) whatever kind of layout you need for each card.

Originally i did a **lot** of nested BorderLayout panels, then moved on to GridBagLayout for almost everything.  While complicated to learn, it is the most flexible.  It probably isn't very guibuilder friendly, though.

Worst case, you could write your own layout...but that's complicated with lots of gotchas...

With swapping/visibility you may require a bunch of validate/invalidate/repaint, or forced calls to doLayout as well.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done it in the past is by using GrdBagLayout.  This allows you to specify where objects will live, whether they will fill or not in their cell, and it sets the size of the cell to the minimum size to let the components play nice with each other.  Follow this with a frame.pack(), and you will have auto-resizing dialogs.  Note, that you have to set the dimensions (iirc, it is minimum and not preferred, although I could be wrong) along with the grid bag constraints (weight, cell, which part of the cell it binds to, etc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't yet have a need to hide a single cell, entire row of cells will do. With GridbagLayout removing components via Container.remove() will cause the space allocated to a row to disappear ?

Comment: The row will still be there, it will just shrink down to whatever size it needs to be.  If there are no components currently in the row, that size will be 0.  Sometimes I have found that the container (jpanel?) needs a revalidate() to do the proper layout, so if it doesn't look like it is responding try that out as well.

Comment: @Rachel: Also, if you want to learn more about gridbaglayout, the tutorial from Oracle is here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html